# conditions statements. why I can't solve this ( there's so many wrong codes I cannot identify)

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
income = float(input("your income: "))
if income <= 100000:
    initalIncome = income * 0.5 
elif income in range (100001,250000):
    initalIncome = income * 0.10
elif income in range (250001,500000):
    initialIncome = income * 0.15
elif income >= 500001:
    initialIncome = income * 0.20
```

print(initialIncome)

#why is it giving the wrong answer?

#I think there's something wrong with the conditions

## I cannot find the right code on how do i find the  final tax in this code

Comment: Please a) [edit] your question to tag the language you're using, b) You need to explain what answer the code IS supposed to produce so that people can understand you completely.

Comment: What is the output of your current program and what is the expected output?

Comment: ```range``` generates integers, but ```income``` is a float, and as such will not be in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the answer you looking for, but you did not create the **InitialIncome** variable. Thus executing your code, this is the result:

```
income = float(input("your income: "))

if income <= 100000:

    initalIncome = income * 0.5 

elif income in range (100001,250000):

    initalIncome = income * 0.10

elif income in range (250001,500000):

    initialIncome = income * 0.15

elif income >= 500001:

    initialIncome = income * 0.20

​

print(initialIncome)

your income:  100

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-306fbda6a7e7> in <module>
      9     initialIncome = income * 0.20
     10 
---> 11 print(initialIncome)

NameError: name 'initialIncome' is not defined
```

Try to add the variable you are looking for with value of 0.
In that case your code works.

```
def income_calc():
    income = float(input("your income: "))
    initialIncome = 0
    
    if income <= 100000:
        initialIncome = income *0.5
    elif income in range (100001, 250000):
        initialIncome = income *0.10
    elif income in range (250001, 500000):
        initialIncome = income *0.15
    elif income >= 500001:
        initialIncome = income *0.20
        
    return initialIncome
```

Executing:

[image: Test]

Comment: File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2216/1135507158.py", line 13
    return initialIncome
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Indentation is not right

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that the parser screwed up the indents. I edited it now. Besides, check the spelling "InitalIncome" vs "InitialIncome"

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the wrong variable

check your spelling for `initialIncome` in each condition